# Find the maximum of $\frac {xyz}{(1+x)(x+y)(y+z)(z+16)}$, given x, y, z are positive real numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Below is my working: 
This is equivalent to the minimum of $$\frac {(1+x)(x+y)(y+z)(z+16)}{xyz}$$
$$=(1+x)\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)\left(1+\frac zy \right)\left( 1 + \frac {16}{z} \right)\\$$
$$= 1+ 16 + \frac {16}{z} + \frac zy + \frac yx + \frac {16y}{xz} +\frac zx + \frac {16y}{x} +x + \frac {16x}{z}+ \frac {xz}{y}+ 16x + y + \frac {16y}{z} + z + 16y \tag{1}\\ \text{By AM-GM}:\qquad \geq16\sqrt[16]{16^8} = 64$$
Thus the maximum value is $\frac {1}{64}$.
However, the solution gives $\frac {1}{81} $ as they used the generalization below : $$ (1+a^4)(1+b^4)(1+c^4)(1+d^4)\geq (1+abcd)^4 $$
Why is my answer incorrect? And how do I know when I can use AM-GM to find the minimum of an expression and when not to, if I don't know the generalization ?
**EDIT**:  Now that I know the equality case never holds, how should I proceed with finding the minimum from (1)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers then prove the inequality $\frac{abc}{(a+1)(a+b)(b+c)(c+16)}≤\frac1{81}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460580/let-a-b-c-be-positive-real-numbers-then-prove-the-inequality-fracabca1) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bxyz%7D%7B(1%2Bx)(x%2By)(y%2Bz)(z%2B16)%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Amaximum%2C%20OR%20content%3Apositive%20real&p=1). Note the other post's question has got the same result as you.

Comment: You have found a lower bound (of your expression). For it to be the minimum, it needs to be the GREATEST lower bound. Equality in your AM-GM occurs when $ 1 = x = y = z = 16$, which clearly cannot be achieved. It is reasonable to expect that values just larger than 64 also cannot be achieved, so 64 isn't the minimum.

Comment: @JohnOmielan No it doesn't answer the question. OP is asking "Why is my answer incorrect", not "How do I do this". $\quad$ To be fair, the link proves a great way to use AM-GM "correctly", where the equality case can hold, and thus we have a minimum. So OP should still look at that link.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for your feedback. However, note the other question basically not only got the same result as in this one, but it also currently ends with "Please let me know how to solve this and also mention where I missed out." That, to me, is a quite similar question to this one, even though IMHO the answer there doesn't really address that part of the question very well. As for whether or not this question can be considered a duplicate of the other question, I'm going to leave it up to other members to decide that.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is incorrect because in order to achieve $1/64$, looking at the equality case, you should have $$1=16=\frac{16}{z}=\frac{z}{y}=\cdots$$which is obviously impossible. In general, if you prove that some expression satisfies $f(x,y,z)\geqslant\lambda$ you should also look if $\lambda$ can actually be achieved, i.e. your bounding wasn't too loose.

Let me give you an example (a random inequality I made up):

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc=1$. Prove that $$\frac{1}{2a+b+c}+\frac{1}{a+2b+c}+\frac{1}{a+b+2c}\leqslant \frac{3}{8}+\frac{a+b+c}{8}.$$

Intuitively, we see that the equality case is $a=b=c=1$. Hence, if we apply am-gm like this: $$2a+b+c\geqslant3\sqrt[3]{2abc}$$then we would have the  equality case $2a=b=c$ so this inequality isn't sharp. Instead, we apply am-gm like this, which "preserves" the equality case (namely $a=b=c)$: $$2a+b+c\geqslant4\sqrt[4]{a^2bc}.$$Now, let's solve the inequality: \begin{align*}\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{2a+b+c}&\leqslant\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{a^2bc}}=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{a}}=\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{\sqrt[4]{bc}}{4} \\ &\leqslant\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{b+c+1+1}{16}=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\sum_{\text{cyc}}a.\end{align*}

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\left\{\frac{1}{81},\{x\to 2,y\to 4,z\to 8\}\right\}$$

Comment: @david-g-stork Mathematica Maximize[] doesn't always find the global maximum.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I meant to write $abc=1$, oops.

Answer (score 0):

You're literally almost there, but unfortunately you complicate the inequality too much. You have using AM-GM that
$$
(1+x)^{-1}(1+y/x)^{-1}(1+z/y)^{-1}(1+16/z)^{-1}\leq\frac{1}{4}\left( (1+x)^{-4}+(1+y/x)^{-4}+(1+z/y)^{-4}+(1+16/z)^{-4}\right),
$$
with equality iff $1+x = 1+y/x = 1+z/y = 1 + 16/z$. Now if you solve for $x,y,z$ and substitute back in the RHS of the inequality, you'll get the answer (it's messy).